# Get the first record from the result set

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql

[image]

I want to only select the highlighted records. how can i do it in sql and preferably in linq. there is a separate table `Emp` with `EmployeeID` as `PK`. 
here is the schema for my tables

[image]

Comment: So you want to group on EmployeeID but what are you using to decide what the 'first one' is?

Comment: @NeilKnight  its looks like i am out rightly requesting for the code but its not like that, i have tried with Rank but couldnt quiet get the results

Comment: @Ray i want to get the `FromDate` but there are duplicate rows which are not undesired but the `FromDate` of first row of every duplicate row will be used as the joining date in the application

Comment: @john I'm trying to get you to define 'first'. From your example, it's not the lowest or the highest, so what criteria are you using to decide first?

Comment: @john, maybe I'm being dense, but I still can't see any criteria you're using to decide on first? Maybe it would help if you could give us the query you've used to get the results show? Or if that's a straight `select * from History` then you need to think about what first really means. Are the `DisignationHistoryID`s [sic] sequential, and you want the lowest? But then your highlighted rows wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be way off but I believe following statement satisfies your requirements

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
         SELECT e.EmployeeID, h.FromDate, h.ToDate
                , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmployeeID ORDER BY DesignationID DESC)
         FROM   employee e
                INNER JOIN history h ON h.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
       ) eh
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: the history table contains the employee deignation history from the first day they joined. on each designation change a new row is added to the history table. what i want is to get the first row of the result set so to find the date on which the employee joined, so when i take the join of employee table and the history table it shows multiple rows for the same employee the `FromDate` of the first row determines the joining date ...

Comment: i tried to run your query but it gave me the following error `The column 'EmployeeID' was specified multiple times for 'eh'.`

Comment: @john - you should replace the `SELECT *` inside the brackets with the columns you'd like to return. I have edited my answer. The query should run now without problems but I did not include *all* columns as per your example.

Comment: you just cannot imagine how thankful i'm to you, i wish i could upvote you a thousand times...tnx alot

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select * from
(select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by FromDate) as rn) sq
where rn = 1
```

Comment: That was what I originally posted but it doesn't work for ID's 256, 257.

Comment: Should work for 256 but not 257, as in the screenshot. It all depends on John posting some clarification as to what he **actually** wants...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're looking for, but try something like this (no subqueries needed and should work on most DBMS, although it looks like your running SQL Server):

```
select t1.DisignationHistoryIDs, t1.employeeId, t1.fromDate from history t1
left join history t2
on t1.employeeId = t2.employeeId and t1.fromDate > t2.fromDate
where t2.fromDate is null
```

This should work to get the oldest fromDate. To get the newest from date just change the `>` for a `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see exactly what you're asking for. The highlighted ID's are just unique occurrences. So you can do this easily with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM MyTable
```

Comment: DISTINCT will give you exactly the list of ID's you've highlighted in yellow. That's what you asked for. If you can be more clear about what you are trying to do, maybe I can make another suggestion.